# Apache Lucene index updating

Tags: java, database, indexing, lucene

I'm working on a Lucene project and I got stuck at one point. After indexing a database with Lucene, I need to automatically detect changes such as adding or deleting rows to the table in the database and then indexing.

Does anyone have an idea about this or a sample project?

Comment: Database insert/update/delete triggers can be used to detect changes (although I am sure there are plenty of other approaches also). Lucene's [IndexWriter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html) has methods for creating, updating, and deleting indexed data. You can write the logic to connect those two things together. Your question is too high-level for a more specific answer, I think.

Comment: Andrewjames has already laid out the common approach that is used.  Here is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795483/lucene-net-index-updates-when-a-manual-change-is-done-in-sql-database#answer-66799438) that elaborates on the concept.

Comment: What I want to do in the database is to import and index the data only by the application,   so I aim to find a suitable solution for this, I cannot create a new table in the database with this application, for example, there is a checksum value. I can understand the changes in the database by importing this value in sql server, but this value is only in sql server I am looking for a solution that is valid for all databases.

Comment: and I also thought about the table hash values, but this time I can't use this solution because it is too costly in terms of time Exactly what I was looking for was checksum value like in sql server, but there should be a solution for all databases