# Updating indexes when the data in the database changes with apache lucene

Tags: java, database, indexing, lucene

I'm working on a Lucene project and I got stuck at one point. After indexing a database with Lucene, I need to automatically detect changes such as adding or deleting rows to the table in the database and then indexing.
What I want to do in the database is to import and index the data only by the application, so I aim to find a suitable solution for this, I cannot create a new table in the database with this application, for example, there is a checksum value. I can understand the changes in the database by importing this value in sql server, but this value is only in sql server I am looking for a solution that is valid for all databases.
and I also thought about the table hash values, but this time I can't use this solution because it is too costly in terms of time Exactly what I was looking for was checksum value like in sql server, but there should be a solution for all database

Does anyone have an idea about this or a sample project?

uses: java16, jdbc, lucene 8.x  and almost all database(sql db)

Comment: This question appears to be very similar to your other recent question [Apache Lucene index updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68220240/apache-lucene-index-updating).

Comment: "_automatically detect changes_" - database triggers; "_index the data only by the application_" - in that case, use the application to perform Lucene index updates (no triggers needed); "_I cannot create a new table in the database_" - OK, but why is this relevant? "_I am looking for a solution that is valid for all databases_" - is that because you are using every database technology which exists? Overall, this question is too broad, I think - and too similar to your previous question. Can you clarify _exactly_ what the _specific_ problem is that you are facing?

Comment: yes, my previous problem continues, so I asked a new question in a more descriptive way. Let me explain it this way: I can only receive data from the database, I cannot send data to the database, I design the program I want to do in this way, so when there is a change in the database, I want to learn it with the data I will import in the database, for example information such as last modified time